# Favorites is/are empty

Tags: meaning, word-choice, grammar, nouns, meaning-in-context

I'm not English native speaker and I'd like to know correct form of this sentence.

If I want to say that my favorites folder is empty what's the verb I should use in this case? I mean when the sentence will be like 'Favorites is/are' empty.

Could find neither singular nor plural mark in most of modern dictionaries.

Comment: You have to learn to recognize the head noun of the noun phrase that serves as the subject, as this is what governs subject–verb agreement. It is not always the first noun in the phrase, nor always the last one either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best answer is *My favorites folder is empty.*

In this case, *folder* is the subject of the sentence and is singular, so you use the singular form *is*.  Here, *favorites* acts as an adjective in the sentence; another way to phrase it would be *My folder of favorites is empty.*

Comment: Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722, please do not use backticked ugly blue monospace for emphasis on ELU  — nor anywhere on the SE network per http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135112. Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/364 for the use–mention distinction, please use an italic face in accord with typographic convention both on this site and in scholarly works. Finally, *favorites* is not an adjective; it is a noun adjunct being used to create a noun–noun compound, like a compound word.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance on typography; I came from StackOverflow and thus I'm used to code highlighting.

Comment: Ah, but that isn’t code.  As the MSE post notes, using backticks to highlight noncode is not well looked upon there either.